# jQuery show and hide does not work consistently

Tags: jquery, random, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

I'm attempting to make a button display random element when clicked using show/hide. It sets up so the element will be hidden first to stop duplicates, then shown. However it sometimes doesn't show.

The Fiddle will be clearer than my explanation: http://jsfiddle.net/qAfqN/.

Simplified code:

```
    this.uiSelect = function(){
    var length = $("#ui li").length;
    var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length);
        $('#ui li').hide();
    $("#ui li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").show();
};

    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#mangle').click(function(){
        uiSelect();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: why dont you print the "ran" result in order to know which element should print and then maybe see whats going on.

Comment: you want to print a random element of each list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:eq()` instead of `:nth-child()`. They have quite a different meaning. The former refers to the element's position in the jQuery collection, while the latter refers to its position among its DOM siblings. These are not the same in your situation.

Consider the following markup:

```
 div
    > ul
        > li 1
        > li 2
    > ul
        > li 3
        > li 4
        > li 5
```

The query `$('div li:eq(2)')` will return `li 3` (indices are zero-based), because that is the third element in the collection. On the other hand, `$('div li:nth-child(3)')` (indices are one-based here, that is why I wrote 3 instead of 2) will return `li 5`, because that is the only third element in its group, among its siblings.

You can even save yourself some ugly string concatenation and duplicate DOM lookups if you use `.eq()` instead of `:eq()` and some chaining like this:

```
$("#ui li").hide().eq(ran).show();
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qAfqN/1/)

Comment: Hey @bažmegakapa thanks for that, however I need to keep the two ul separate (in your example markup) but connected. For instance if the 2nd li of any #ui ul will always display together. My original example does this OK, it's just the attribute isn't applied 100% of the time. Thanks

Comment: @atomictom Then you have a problem with `length`. Based on the explanation I guess you can work that out. Ask if not.

Comment: Ah yes! I understand, the variable length was doubled because of the extra ul so it was looking for, for example, 10 values when there were only 5. I've edited this fiddle which is a cheaty version of what I need and works perfectly, [http://jsfiddle.net/qAfqN/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/qAfqN/5/). It's too late for me to figure how to work it out properly, but I might take you up on your help if I can't figure it out later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, but I am not sure if this is what you want http://jsbin.com/ibasuv/1/edit

```
var pickRandom = function(selector){
  var lis = $(selector).find('li');
  lis.hide();

  var size = lis.size();

  var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*size);
  $(selector).find('li').eq(random).show();
};
```

I put a div closing tag for the second div, I think

Comment: Ah yeah, it's definitely displaying 100% of the time which is way better, however it's only displaying one of the two ul. [I had a go butchering your work](http://jsbin.com/ixiyup/1/) and got it to display two ul however it causes the same problem I had before, in which it displays intermittently. Thanks anyhow